# how to add new element in all subarray in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add new element at the end of each sub array

```
$a1 =   array(
            array('name'=>"Dog",'cate'=>"Cat"), 
            array('name'=>"Puppy",'cate'=>"Kitten"), 
            array('name'=>"happy",'cate'=>"lucky")
        );
```

here i want to add 'test'=>"test" after "cate" in each sub array.
I have tried it using map but its not working. I want to result like that:

```
$a1 =   array(
            array('name'=>"Dog",'cate'=>"Cat",'test'=>"test"), 
            array('name'=>"Puppy",'cate'=>"Kitten",'test'=>"test"), 
            array('name'=>"happy",'cate'=>"lucky",'test'=>"test")
        );
```

how it is possible.

Comment: You should have gone through php manual, you can do this by iterating through the main array element using foreach as well as array_map function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `array_map`-

```
$a1 = array(
        array('name'=>"Dog",'cate'=>"Cat"), 
        array('name'=>"Puppy",'cate'=>"Kitten"), 
        array('name'=>"happy",'cate'=>"lucky")
    );

$new = array_map(function($x) {
    $x['test'] = 'test';
    return $x;
}, $a1);
```

**Update**

```
$new = array_map(function($x) use($message) {
    $x['test'] = $message;
    return $x;
}, $a1);
```

Comment: hi but i want it using with new element value from variable Like:
$x['test'] = $message;
istead of
 $x['test'] = 'test';

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you've tried exactly, but this array map will work:

```
$a1 = array_map(function (array $a) { return $a + array('test' => 'test'); }, $a1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop the array and add the value to each array within it.

```
foreach($a1 as $k => $v) {
  $a1[$k][$newkey] = $newvalue;
}
```